# How can I disable the serial debugging console?

Tags: android, serial-console, android-things

I am using raspberry pi 3b model with android things. I need to attach GPS module NEO6mv2 with the pi. How can I disable the serial debugging console?

Comment: But if you disable your serial debugging console, you can no longer debug your NEO GPS module.

Comment: How shall I connect the gps module then without disabling the serial debug console

Comment: Ah, I am using Rpi Raspbian and IDLE python 3.5.3, NOT Android Things. I am using Desktop IDLE Shell for debugging.  Rpi has a built in UART.  I also have  a couple of more USB to UART adpaters/cables.  So I can play with many GPS modules and other serial devices at the same time.   I am not using Android in Rpi, because I heard that it is very slow.